# Github pages uses same "pages build and deployment" regardless of what repo pushes to it

Tags: github, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

I have two website repos which I have been experimenting with.
One is built with Hugo, one is an export through emacs-org mode.

The Hugo repo has a `gh-pages.yml` which specifies the github actions to be performed when committed.

I have been swapping between which repo I push from, by using `git push -F origin/main`.

When I do this, regardless of which repo I've pushed from, the github actions is the same, which seems to use jekyll to try and build the website. However, I haven't specified jekyll in either, so i'm not sure where this comes from. This results in a 404 error for the Hugo repo (because the correct github-actions are not being performed), and the correct website for the org-emacs repo.

With github pages, is there a standard action being performed on each commit? If so, why won't a `gh-pages.yml` file located in `.github/workflows/` change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of [custom workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow) to deploy to GitHub Pages is determined by repo's settings:

**Settings -> Pages -> Build and deployment -> Source**

You need to select ***GitHub Actions*** as *Source*. When you do, GitHub should suggest a starter workflow for you. In case of a repo that I worked on which uses a custom workflow for deployment, the file is named ***pages.yml*** but I guess *gh-pages.yml* might be a correct name as well.

Comment: Just to follow up, this comment helped me deploy the repo correctly.

I went to Settings -> Pages -> Build and deployment -> Source and changed to the correct branch, which was gh-pages. As it was previously deploying from main. 

This was keeping in line with this tutorial: https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/